# Determine when header sticks in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I need to figure out what the current section header is when scrolling based on which header view is currently stuck to the top of the table. I've tried this code but it gets the header once it's midway through scrolling instead of once it's stuck to the top:

```
        var paths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()
        var topCellPath: NSIndexPath = paths?.first as NSIndexPath
        if topCellPath.row != 0 {
            // header stuck but not really
        }
```

Any help?

Comment: `topCellPath.section` will tell you the number of the section of the top cell.  Why do you care whether or not the top cell is the first row of its section?

Comment: I need to highlight buttons which represent the headers as you scroll. And I want these to change as soon as the new header gets stuck.

Comment: The headers are section headers... so again, why does it matter what row that cell is in its section?

Comment: Ahhh thank you. I just realized I had the code in the wrong spot. I put it in cellForRowAtIndexPath method instead of scrollViewDidScroll. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSIndexPath` has to members.  `section` and `row`.

The `row` member gives you zero information about what section you are in.  All it does it tell you what row this path is in the given section, identified by the `section` member.

We can determine what section an `NSIndexPath` belongs to by checking the `section` member:

```
switch topCellPath.section {
    case 0:
        // top visible cell is in section 0
    case 1:
        // top visible cell is in section 1
    // etc. etc.
    default:
        // top visible cell is in some other section
}
```

And we already know how to relate this section number to our data model... we used this to set the header in:

```
tableView(UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection: Int) -> UIView
```